# UIPopover: Orientation Change Handling

Tags: ipad, dictionary, uipopovercontroller, orientation-changes, uipopover

we have some issues with the native popover controller used on the ipad, maybe someone of you already found some work-arounds.

Issue 1:
Some of our Popovers used in a form have also a navigationcontroller embedded, so if we dismiss the popover after orientation change and show it again, all data would be lost. Surely we can store the data in a cache but this wouldnt be nice.

Issue 2:
We are using a mapView which contains various annotations which are clustered for performance reasons by SuperPin Framework. After orientation change, the popover is misplaced sometimes.

Is there clean generic solution to cache frame and view and show the popover correctly after orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue 2 I suggest that you present the popover again from its anchor point . Something like this :

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    //Present the popover here from its anchor point.This will take care for both orientations.
}
```

This works for me.
For Issue 1 other folks would be able to provide better guidance.